# Text Frames in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working on layouts for a project. When I type in captions for photos, there is a text frame around the captions and it won't let me "snuggle" the caption directly under the photo. It either bounces up too close to the photo or too far away. I have no control of it. Why? I've used InDesign for years, and this is the first time this has happened. I've shut off the text wrap and have searched trying to find a solution.
Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without more information. Perhaps in this case a screen recording showing the issue could help.

Comment: using "lock to baseline grid"?